# std::to_chars() minimal floating point buffer size

Tags: c++, formatting, c++17, number-formatting

Given a generic integer type `IntType`, it is easy to determine the necessary buffer type for a [`std::to_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars) operation for base-10 numbers:

```
std::array<char, std::numeric_limits<IntType>::digits10 + 1 + std::is_signed<IntType>::value> buf;
```

Since `std::to_chars` doesn't NUL-terminate, and only adds the digits (and a possible preceding `'-'`, if signed), this should work for all built-in integer types. The `+ 1` is needed because [digits10 for integral types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10) returns the floor of the base-10 logarithm, not the ceiling.

This leads to the question: what is the minimal buffer size for a floating point `std::to_chars` call given a generic `FloatType` to be converted without loss (writing all decimal digits), using each of the [`std::chars_format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/chars_format) values?

Comment: [`std::numeric_limits::max_digits10`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10)?

Comment: @Jarod42 - Unfortunately that doesn't work for fixed point notation, nor does it include the number of characters that could be added due to an exponent being written in scientific notation.

Comment: Then maybe `std::numeric_limits::max_digits10+10`. A few extra bytes won't be missed.

Comment: Yes, that may work for scientific notation (at least with current sizes of floating point types, which makes it a bit brittle for potential floating point sizes in the future), but still doesn't work for fixed point notation, which may take hundreds of characters to store without loss. Understandably, each of the `std::chars_format` values will have different minimal buffer sizes.

Comment: @owacoder: "*which may take hundreds of characters to store without loss*" A `float` (IEEE-754 BINARY32 format) will never require "hundreds" of decimal digits to allow for full round-tripping.

Comment: You only need enough digits for the precision of the type.  `to_char` can't be more precise then a type passed to it.

Comment: @NicolBolas @NathanOliver - True, but the question is about the more general case for *each* of the `std::chars_format` values, not just for the specific case of the smallest buffer for completely lossless conversion, and encompassing any floating point type, not just `float`. If using `std::chars_format::fixed`, the minimal buffer size becomes a matter of how many digits are actually written to the output buffer (possibly hundreds for `double` or even thousands for `long double`), not just the maximum exponent of the provided type.

Comment: @owacoder: If you don't care about lossless conversion, what does it matter if some irrelevant, repeating digit is missing? That is, what does it matter if you get "0.0000001234234" instead of "0.0000001234234444444444444444443" or something? Under which circumstances do you think `max_digits10` won't give you "enough" digits, however you define that?

Comment: @NicolBolas - Because fixed notation numbers with positive exponents don't have insignificant or irrelevant digits, unlike your example with a negative exponent. `max_digits10` with fixed point notation using a large value like 1e38 will fail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that the minimal buffer required is different depending on the floating point format desired. Using `max_digits10` and `max_exponent10` is always enough to determine the minimum number of characters necessary for base-10 output, assuming one doesn't want to output more precision than the floating point type contains.

This problem is not just limited to `to_chars`, either. The C standard library functions in the `printf` family will have the same behavior, so this applies with equal weight in C as it does in C++.

- `std::chars_format::scientific` or `%e (printf specifier)`:

  ```
  template<typename T>
  constexpr int log10ceil(T num) {
      return num < 10? 1: 1 + log10ceil(num / 10);
  }

  std::array<char, 4 + 
                   std::numeric_limits<FloatType>::max_digits10 + 
                   std::max(2, log10ceil(std::numeric_limits<FloatType>::max_exponent10))
            > buf;
  ```

  The function `log10ceil` allows constexpr evaluation of how many digits are in the largest exponent possible. At least 2 digits must be present in the exponent per the standard, hence the test against a minimum exponent width. The precision used when writing must be no larger than `max_digits10 - 1`. Using this exact precision will provide lossless conversion to a string representation.

  The addition of 4 characters accommodates the possible sign, the decimal point, and the `"e+"` or `"e-"` in the output.
- `std::chars_format::fixed` or `%f (printf specifier)`:

  ```
  std::array<char, 2 + 
                   std::numeric_limits<FloatType>::max_exponent10 +
                   std::numeric_limits<FloatType>::max_digits10
            > buf;
  ```

  Again, the precision used must be no larger than `max_digits10 - 1`. Using this exact precision will provide lossless conversion to a string representation.

  The addition of 2 characters accommodates the possible sign and the decimal point in the output.
- `std::chars_format::general` or `%g (printf specifier)`:

  For the `general` case, the minimal buffer is always the same as the `scientific` case. **However**, the precision used must be no larger than **`max_digits10`** for lossless conversion to a string representation, rather than subtracting one as mentioned above.

Note that in all these examples, the buffer is **exactly** the size of the largest string representation. If a NUL-terminator or other content is needed, the size must be increased accordingly.

Comment: Can we somehow determine the needed buffer size for a given value, format and precision upfront?

Comment: @Viatorus - It should be possible with new versions of C++ to use constexpr evaluation for a given value, format, and precision and then extract the size of the buffer needed for the value. For example, using snprintf at compile time. Doing so is beyond the scope of this answer though.

Comment: `std::snprintf()` does have the useful capability of returning the number of characters it _would_ have emitted were the buffer big enough, and works sanely with `nullptr, 0` as output buffer.  I used that effectively to [Create a C++ string using printf-style formatting][/q/187183/75307]  over on our sister site.

Answer (score -2):

```cpp
template <std::floating_point F>
constexpr int max_fixed_length = 2 + std::numeric_limits<F>::max_digits10 + std::numeric_limits<F>::max_exponent10;

template <typename F>
constexpr int max_exponent_digits10 = 0;

template <>
constexpr int max_exponent_digits10<float> = 2; // FLT_MAX_10_EXP = 38

template <>
constexpr int max_exponent_digits10<double> = 3; // DBL_MAX_10_EXP = 308

template <>
constexpr int max_exponent_digits10<long double> = 4; // LDBL_MAX_10_EXP = 4932

template <std::floating_point F>
constexpr int max_scientific_length = 2 + std::numeric_limits<F>::max_digits10 + 2 + max_exponent_digits10<F>;

template <typename F>
constexpr int max_exponent_digits2 = 0;

template <>
constexpr int max_exponent_digits2<float> = 3; // FLT_MAX_EXP = 128

template <>
constexpr int max_exponent_digits2<double> = 4; // DBL_MAX_EXP = 1024

template <>
constexpr int max_exponent_digits2<long double> = 5; // LDBL_MAX_EXP = 16384

template <std::floating_point F>
constexpr int max_hex_length = 2 + 1 + std::numeric_limits<F>::digits / 4 + 2 + max_exponent_digits2<F>;
```

```cpp
int main() {
    using F = float;

    char buf1[8192] = {};
    char buf2[8192] = {};
    F FLT_MIN = -std::numeric_limits<F>::min();
    F FLT_MAX = -std::numeric_limits<F>::max();
    std::chars_format fmt = std::chars_format::fixed;
    std::size_t precision = 30;

    {//std::to_chars_result to_chars(char* first, char* last, float value);
        constexpr std::size_t max = std::min(max_fixed_length<F>, max_scientific_length<F>);

        std::to_chars(buf1, buf1 + max, FLT_MIN);
        std::to_chars(buf2, buf2 + max, FLT_MAX);
        std::cout << "FLT_MIN = " << buf1 << "\n";
        std::cout << "FLT_MAX = " << buf2 << "\n\n";
        std::memset(buf1, 0, sizeof(buf1));
        std::memset(buf2, 0, sizeof(buf2));
    }

    {//std::to_chars_result to_chars(char* first, char* last, float value, std::chars_format fmt);

        std::size_t max = fmt == std::chars_format::fixed ? max_fixed_length<F>
            : (fmt == std::chars_format::hex ? max_hex_length<F>
            : max_scientific_length<F>);

        std::to_chars(buf1, buf1 + max, FLT_MIN, fmt);
        std::to_chars(buf2, buf2 + max, FLT_MAX, fmt);
        std::cout << "FLT_MIN = " << buf1 << "\n";
        std::cout << "FLT_MAX = " << buf2 << "\n\n";
        std::memset(buf1, 0, sizeof(buf1));
        std::memset(buf2, 0, sizeof(buf2));
    }

    {//std::to_chars_result to_chars(char* first, char* last, float value, std::chars_format fmt, int precision);

        std::size_t max = 2 + precision + 1;
        max += fmt == std::chars_format::fixed ? std::numeric_limits<F>::max_exponent10
            : (fmt == std::chars_format::hex ? 2 + max_exponent_digits2<F>
            : 2 + max_exponent_digits10<F>);

        std::to_chars(buf1, buf1 + max, FLT_MIN, fmt, precision);
        std::to_chars(buf2, buf2 + max, FLT_MAX, fmt, precision);
        std::cout << "FLT_MIN = " << buf1 << "\n";
        std::cout << "FLT_MAX = " << buf2 << "\n\n";
        std::memset(buf1, 0, sizeof(buf1));
        std::memset(buf2, 0, sizeof(buf2));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).